# How can I configure GridDB to handle high concurrent connections efficiently and effectively?

Tags: griddb

I am using GridDB and I am concerned about hitting a connection limit or degrading performance as the user base continues to grow.

My question is;
Is there a predefined connection limit in GridDB?
How does GridDB manage multiple concurrent connections? Is there a way to optimize the configuration for high concurrency in GridDB?

Comment: The application which is running on the user side is connecting to the DB directly?

Comment: Yes it is connecting directly.

Comment: That's untypical. Does it mean the username and password for the DB is stored in the user application? Isn't there a risk a user may extract the user/password and connect to the DB using a DB client? Someone may access restricted data or delete the whole db. I just want to make sure I understand your architecture.